# Why doesn't empty(0) return false?

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Stack{
private $_data = array();
private $_end = null;
public function push($data){
    if($this->_end === null){
        $this->_end = 0;
    }else{
        $this->_end = $this->_end + 1;
    }
    $this->_data[$this->_end] = $data;
}

public function pop(){
    if(empty($this->_data)){
        return false;
    }

    $ret = $this->_data[$this->_end];

    array_splice($this->_data, $this->_end);
    $this->_end--;

    return $ret;
}

public function getData(){
    return $this->_data;
}
}

// test
$stack = new Stack();
$stack->push(0);
$pop_data = $stack->pop();
var_dump($pop_data, $stack->getData());
```

Why doesn't `empty(0)` return `false`? I push `0` to the `pop_data`. `empty($this->_data)` should return `false`, but the result of the test is `int(0)`. I am puzzled.

Comment: I do not see how this can be true. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php says that empty returns a bool, not an int.

Comment: @Patashu i dont think he's actually questioning the php function but the function he's using together with empty() renrenshang I think it's cause rest of the function is running after try making rest of the code inside a else statment

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->_data)`.

Comment: Where's your call to `empty(0)`? I cannot find it. Which of the calls in your code puzzles you? What does this call do? What do you think it should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->_data in your code is an array.

Replace your line with this(to evaluate the passed zero value):

```
$this->_data[$this->_end];
```